# Error when binding nested object in collectionView MAUI #

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I'm working on an POC in MAUI C#. In this POC I need to bind a object with a nested List in a collectionView.
I'm new in MVVm pattern and MAUI.

My code:
View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="testbinding.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testbinding.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="local:TestViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:testbinding.Model">

  
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding TestModel.Toto}" EmptyView="pas de data" IsGrouped="True">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Toto" >
                        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="300000" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding Plop}"></Label>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
   

</ContentPage>
```

View.cs:

```
using testbinding.ViewModel;

namespace testbinding;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    
        BindingContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
```

}

Viewmodel :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using testbinding.Model;

namespace testbinding.ViewModel
{
    public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TestModel TestModel { get; } = new TestModel();


        public TestViewModel()
        {
            TestModel = new TestModel();
            
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testbinding.Model
{
    public class TestModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       private string id;
       private string name;
       private List<Toto> toto;
        public string Id 
        { 
          get { return id; }
          set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id)); }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name)); }
        }

        public List<Toto> Toto
        {
            get { return getList(); }
            set { toto =  value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Toto)); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        private List<Toto> getList()
        {
            List<Toto> totos = new List<Toto>();
            totos.Add(new Toto { Id = 1, Plop = "plop" } );
            totos.Add(new Toto { Id = 2, Plop = "plop2" } );
            totos.Add(new Toto { Id = 3, Plop = "plop24" } );
            totos.Add(new Toto { Id = 4, Plop = "plop241" } );

            return totos;
        }
    
    }
}
```

nested model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testbinding.Model
{
    public class Toto : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id { get; set; }
        private string  plop { get; set; }
        public int Id 
        { get { return id; }
          set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id)); }
        }
        public string  Plop
        {
            get { return plop; }
            set { plop = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Plop)); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

With this code I got this error:

Défaillance irrémédiable (0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) or
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.NavigationFailed was unhandled.

I'm new in C# MAUI did some one has solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I’d start by setting isGrouped to false.  Your data does not appear to be grouped

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer it's the solution !! It helps me a lot!